# node.js router - how to access router.post to stop future code execution?

Tags: node.js, express, post

User is lazy, don't want to wait for data and quit the page. How I can access router.post to stop further code execution?

APP.JS FILE (backend):

```
var express = require('express');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');
var connectRedis = require('connect-redis');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');
var compression = require('compression');
var RedisStore = connectRedis(expressSession);
var io = require('socket.io');
var data = require('./routes/data.js');
var page = require('./routes/page.js');
var app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/pages');
app.use('/', data);
app.use('/page', page);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.request.session; // session
    socket.id; // id
    soc.on('user-abort', function(id){
        id.specificUser; // we need to close this connection and all the code that is synchronized with this id/socket
    });
});
```

PAGE.JS FILE (router):

```
router.post('/page', function(req, res, next)
{
    //we render page so we can send the proper data
    res.render('page');
    req.session // we get id here
    var data = 'data';
    // let suposse we send data to the user partialy:
    function sendData(){
        console.log("data");
        setTimeout(sendData, 1000);
    }
    setTimeout(sendData, 1000);
    // now user quit the page - how I can access router.post to stop the code execution ???
});

module.exports = router;
```

PAGE.EJS FILE (user side HTML):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e)
{
    socket.emit('abort', {id : specificUser}, function(){
        //user quit the page
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, you can't, at least not with the code that you're showing.

The reason is that by using `res.render()`, you are causing the connection to the browser to get closed by your server, which means there is no way to detect if the user is quitting the page (well, you could try using `window.onunload` and sending special "user quit the page" request to your server, but a) that won't be reliable and b) you'd have to match up that request to the particular timer that was started on behalf of that specific user).

However, you are suggesting that your code would send additional data to the browser, which it doesn't (because like I said, `res.render()` will close the connection when it's done), so my guess is that your actual code looks differently, in which case it *may* be possible to detect the user from navigating away from the page.

**EDIT**: I would suggest moving the "periodic update" code to the `socket.io` part of your app. The reason is that HTTP requests are ephemeral, and you're basically starting a new timer for every request.

If you're adamant on running the updates from the request handler, I would probably use a global object to link session id's (which are known to both the HTTP request handler and the `socket.io` handler) with `socket.io` connections, and store timer references and a boolean to reflect if the user has left the page.

Something like this (very much untested):

```
const connections = {}; // this object should accessible in both the socket.io handlers and the HTTP handlers

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  const sid = socket.request.session.id;

  // cleanup previous connections
  if (sid in connections) {
    clearTimeout(connections[sid].timer);
    delete connections[sid];
  }

  // create new connection
  connections[sid] = {
    timer: null,
    connected: true,
    socket,
  };

  socket.on('user-abort', function(id) {
    clearTimeout(connections[sid].timer);
    connections[sid].connected = false;
  });
});

…

router.post('/page', function(req, res, next) {
  const sid = req.session.id;

  res.render('page');

  function sendData() {
    if (! connections[sid]?.connected) return;
    connections[sid].socket.emit('hello', 'world');
    connections[sid].timer = setTimeout(sendData, 1000);
  }
  sendData();
});
```

But again, I would move `sendData` to the `socket.io` handler, I can see a whole lot of issues that may occur using the above code.

Comment: Robert, Thanks for valuable input! The code is simplified. I'm using socket.io to send user the data, so I must render the page to have a point, I can send the data to. I have window.onbeforeunload that send info (by socket) that user quit the page. I receive the socket data in my app (with the session I need to target), but dunno how to get inside  router.post (this specific session)... to quit the async code execution. If you have any idea, let me know. I wanted to use abort controller, but maybe there is something else you have in mind. I did dig a bit a did not found any valuable solution.

Comment: @proto do you actually need to run the long-running code inside the request handler?

Comment: Yea... I have whole app that is working that way :( I'm kind of new in node environment I have problems passing data from route to route, using modules that not mutate global variables, etc. So I prefer (if possible) to keep this structure (hey it works so far!). I can send more code (with socket data, session, bigger part of the structure) if it helps.

Comment: Typically, `socket.io` handlers run separate from HTTP request handlers specifically to prevent situations like this. More code would be helpful because I don't understand how, for instance, you retrieve the correct `socket.io` connection that belongs to a particular HTTP request.

Comment: Updated: let me know if everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If the "further code execution" that you want to prevent is asynchronous (for example, fetches data from a database), you can listen to the `close` event of the incoming request, if you send the HTML page with `res.write`, without `res.end`:

```js
app.use("/path", function(req, res) {
  var abort;
  res.on("close", function() {
    abort = true;
  });
  function sendData() {
    if (abort)
      console.log("aborted");
    else {
      console.log("<some data>");
      setTimeout(sendData, 1000);
    }
  }
  res.write(`<html>...</html>`);
  sendData();
});
```

Comment: I considered this for an answer too, but since OP is using `res.render()` to send back a response from the request handler you can't use it (the request gets closed after the response is sent back)

Comment: But the request might be aborted _before_ `res.render` is executed.

Comment: True, but that's not the problem they are trying to solve :D

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AgWNkaA

Very interesting discussion! To sum this up - app is creating a session, get socket id, render a page, so the data can be send by sockets (or ajax whatever,but the data is based on heavy CPU/memory operations).User receive part of the data,but decided he can't wait (means something happened and he cannot complete the task at this time).So on exit (onbeforeunload) he emit abort (disconnect) socket with his (user) id (he can grab it from a cookie or app can send it to him, whatever).App grab this abort socket, means it have the user it want close all async code on.

Comment: Now the problem is I don't know how to pass abort (for example via abort controller) to this specific router.post that is still mutating the data. I won't be sending any more data to the user (so res.render is not a problem I think) I just need to shutdown all async calculations that are still pending, that are connected with this specific user.

Probably this app is designed in a wrong way... Router.post file has 3MB size, but it works so far cause on every call it has the specific user data.

Comment: When I try user modules or any different approach it was hell cause of async race conditions, globals pollution (different users data merge), etc.

If any of you can show me in a simple example how to build this app properly or give some feedback, or solve the problem it will be much appreciated :)